# Understanding ASP.Net session life time

Tags: asp.net, session, iis, asp-classic, lifetime

I am confused about ASP or ASP.Net session life time (or life cycle) concepts. More specifically, my confusions are:

1. How does IIS decide when a new session starts and an existing session ends? Especially how does IIS decide whether a session continues or ends when we call redirect code?
2. How can we set session expire time? (Currently I only know to set it through `web.config sessionState` item.)
3. Is it possible for one session to access another session's variables?

Answer (score 5):

Session is generally handled by generating a unique identifier as a cookie on the clients machine. This is usually a session cookie, so you can't easily get to it. When you visit a site that uses sessions, it looks for this cookie. If it doesn't find it, it creates a new one, thus creating a new session.

One way to set the expire time is in the web.config, you can also set it in IIS by going to your website properties -> Home directory tab ->Configuration button -> Options Tab -> Session Timeout.

You will not be able to access someone elses session data.

Comment: Cool answer. Two more comments, 1. "This is usually a session cookie, so you can't easily get to it. When you visit a site that uses sessions, it looks for this cookie. If it doesn't find it, it creates a new one, thus creating a new session." -- is IIS or our application code underlying implements the logics? 2. "You will not be able to access someone elses session data." -- guaranteed by ASP.Net runtime?

Comment: This is fully built in to asp.net (or asp) and happens automatically if you have the session state element setup in your web.config: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6bb9cz9(VS.80).aspx

Not being able to access someone elses session data is guarenteed by the way sessions are handled. All data is tied directly the unique identier in the cookie. The only was someone could get to it is if they copy someone elses cookie to their own machine, or modified their cookie to use someone elses GUID, which they would not be able to guess. You shouldn't need to worry about either of these.

Comment: Thanks @AaronS, 1. I think you mean even if I do not use any session variables exploicitly in my code, if I enable session state in my web.config, then a unique session cookie will be created and transferred back and forth between continuous interaction between end user and web server? 2. Will the session cookie be shared between different browser sessions on the same client computer when accessing the same web site? 3. About the session expire time we set, does the expire time mean idle time or the whole life time of session (from begin to the end) even if user is active?

Comment: 1. You are correct, even if you don't use them, the cookie will be present if set up in your web.config. 2.Your session variables will never be available to another browser session. If you have variables that you want to keep between sessions, you should put them into a physical cookie, with an expiration date http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178194.aspx 3. The session times are based on the last time the server detected any activity. The session will stay active forever if the user keeps using it.

Comment: @AaronS, 1. any ways to extend session expire time; 2. any event listener we could implement to react to session expire event? 3. how do we know for current session when session will expire?

Comment: Your global.asax has both session_begin and session_end methods you can use. I'm not sure if there is a way to determine when a current session will expire. You may have to just take a datetime stamp of the time the page was sent to the client, and add 20 minutes to it, or higher if you increase it.

Comment: @AaronS, 1. I want to confirm with you you mean in session_end method, we could add 20 minutes, could you help to point me to the API please? 2. Since cookie could be shared between different browser sessions to the same web site, and session is implemented in cookie, why session variables can not be shared between different browser sessions? 3. how to set session expire in legacy ASP? still in web.config?

Comment: 1 and 3) It's been a while since I've worked in classic ASP, but I would set your session timeout in IIS, as I mentioned in my original post. session_end is asp.net specific, I don't remember there being a classic asp equivalent. I could be wrong. 2) the reason is because there are two types of cookies, session cookies and physical cookies. Session cookies only exist in ram on the client machine, and not as physical cookies you can browse to. When the user closes their browser, all session cookies are automatically destroyed.

Comment: Thanks @AaronS, what happens when we retrieve session variable? Return String.Empty value?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you're asking. But you should make sure a session variable exists before you try to pull the value out of it.

if(Session["KeyName"] != null)
{
   myvariable = Session["KeyName"];
}

Comment: @AaronS, sorry I mean if session is expired, what value we retrieves from a session variable? String.Empty?

Comment: Actually the reason why I need such tricky to check empty is, I need to implement such scenario -- when the session timeout, I will redirect user to the login page again. Any ideas how to implement this gracefully without checking string empty?

Comment: in asp.net you can do this: if (Session.IsNewSession) 
   Response.Redirect("login.aspx");


However, I believe in classic asp you do need to check to see if a session variable is null and then redirect them manually.

Comment: @AaronS, is there any way in classic ASP to set session never expire?

Answer (score 5):

1. Session starts because the request does not contain a session cookie or the session cookie it does contain no longer maps to a session.  A session ends by a) it has sat idle with no further requests referencing it for the timeout period. b) Its deliberately aborted by code. c) In-process session dies when the process does, e.g. when the app is recycled.
2. Different ways to change the timeout are basically modifing the web.config anyway or a config file from which the value is inherited.
3. Not unless the session object is deliberately placed by code somewhere that another session can access it.

Comment: Cool! For 1, you said "1.Session starts because the request does not contain a session cookie or the session cookie it does contain no longer maps to a session" -- my confusion is who is responsible to implement the logics about session cookie, ASP.Net runtime? 2. For 3, I think you mean reference the same object instance from different sessions, so modify the reference in one session will impact the value retrived in another session?

Comment: ASP.NET runtime handles all the session creation and cookie creation for you.  Fundementally you could (Don't actually do this!!) maintain a static Dictionary<string, IHttpSessionState> and stick a reference to each session object as it gets created.  Using some string key of your own invention you could then have code running in one session access the session object of another.  I can't think of a sensible reason for actually doing this, I'm fairly sure it won't end well.

Comment: If session is expired, what value we retrieves from a session variable? String.Empty?

Comment: It will be Null.  I would use String.IsNullOrEmpty method to test its value.

Comment: Actually the reason why I need such tricky to check empty is, I need to implement such scenario -- when the session timeout, I will redirect user to the login page again. Any ideas how to implement this gracefully without checking string empty?

Comment: if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Session["AmILoggedIn") { //do stuff about not being logged in }

Comment: @AnthonyWJones, is there any way in classic ASP to set session never expire?

Comment: In ASP-Classic just set the ASP Session timeout to an unreasonably long time and ensure the App Pool timeout is just as unreasonable.

Answer (score 3):

You can set session timeout programatically with:

```
Session.Timeout = 60;
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget the AppPool settings too...by default (IIS 6 anyway) it will recycle every 120 minutes.  So it's possible that someone could lose their session in less than the set Session_Timeout value.