# ASP.NET session expires too fast on production

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

I set session timeout to 3650 days in `Startup.Auth.cs`. On my computer it works fine, session never expires but in production it expires under 30 minutes.

```
    app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
    {
        AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
        LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
        Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
        {

            OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
            validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromDays(3650),
            regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
        },
        ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(3650),


    });
```

By the way I know that there are two lines of code to handle session time. At first, I was using just

```
validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromDays(3650),
```

and then when i saw that it didn't work i added the last one but it still doesn't work on production.

So what else should i do?

Answer (score 3):

Even when a cookie could remain for days before expiring, the cookie contains a session id that maps to an object at server.

> The default behavior is to store session variables in the memory space
>   of the ASP.NET worker process.

Asp.Net applications runs on IIS which performs application recycling, killing threads and restarting your application periodically to avoid problems like memory leaks. This would also make you lose session.

> Session starts because the request does not contain a session cookie
>   **or the session cookie it does contain no longer maps to a session.** A
>   session ends by a) it has sat idle with no further requests
>   referencing it for the timeout period. b) Its deliberately aborted by
>   code. **c) In-process session dies when the process does, e.g. when the
>   app is recycled**.

In other words, by default you cannot expect Session object to live 3650 days (10 years) [unless you change IIS configuration and disable recycling and idling](https://thycotic.force.com/support/s/article/Changing-IIS-to-not-stop-worker-process-in-IIS-7-and-8), which is dangerous.

> However, you can also specify that session state should be stored in a
>   separate process, **in a SQL Server database, or in a custom data
>   source**.

Consider increasing "time intervals" for recycling in IIS.

References:

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/951173/2516718